# Not to print None for keys without values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

A dictionary was created with keys. Later some of the keys got values updated.

When printing the keys in a For loop, the keys without values, prints None.

```
ma_dict = dict.fromkeys(["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"])
ma_dict.update({"David" : "Front", "Mike" : "Middle"})

for each in ["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"]:
    print (each, ma_dict[each])
```

It prints:

```
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate None
Lilly None
```

What is the way not to print the None?

```
# outputs wanted
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate 
Lilly
```

Not to use an If statement, such as:

```
ma_dict = dict.fromkeys(["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"])
ma_dict.update({"David" : "Front", "Mike" : "Middle"})

for each in ["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"]:
    if ma_dict[each] != None:
        print (each, ma_dict[each])
    else:
        print (each)
```

Comment: maybe a default dict of empty strings, import from collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `if` is appriopate here, but if you must  *Not to use an If statement* AT ANY PRICE then do

```
ma_dict = dict.fromkeys(["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"])
ma_dict.update({"David" : "Front", "Mike" : "Middle"})
for each in ["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"]:
    print(each, [ma_dict[each],""][ma_dict[each] is None])
```

output

```
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate
Lilly
```

Comment: Why are you using this approach?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga per OP requirement *Not to use an if statement*

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for printing, you might consider using a dictionary comprehension to replace `None` with empty strings:

```
d = {k: ma_dict[k] if ma_dict[k] is not None else "" for k in ma_dict}
for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate 
Lilly
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @masasa:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ma_dict = defaultdict(str)
ma_dict.update({"David" : "Front", "Mike" : "Middle"})

for each in ["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"]:
    print (each, ma_dict[each])
```

It prints:

```
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate 
Lilly
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use an `if` condition and As @masasa has suggested, You could use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
ma_dict = defaultdict.fromkeys(["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"], '')
ma_dict.update({"David" : "Front", "Mike" : "Middle"})
for each in ["David","Mike","Kate","Lilly"]:
    print (each, ma_dict.get(each))
```

```
David Front
Mike Middle
Kate 
Lilly
```